# How to get the figure produced by the fitter package?

Tags: python, plot, distribution, normal-distribution

I am using the fitter package to fit many distributions simultaneously and visualize the outcome ([documentation](https://fitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). However, I want access to the figure it produces.

```
from fitter import Fitter
f = Fitter(data=df, distributions=['gamma', "norm", 'invgauss'], timeout=100)
f.fit()
f.summary()
```

`f.summary()` returns two objects, a dataframe of the numerical outcomes and a plot visualizing the outcome. I need to be able to store the figure into a variable, such that I can use it in my data visualization dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found the answer:

```
f.plot_pdf()
f.hist()
```